# im getting a error 401 unauthorized using the spotify api in c# wpf

Tags: c#, api, spotify

Im getting this Error. System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.' Code is provided below.

When i take out the method "PrintUsefulData(api)", everything seems to work fine
that method has a http client webrequest. Im trying to request the following https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _clientId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_clientId)
            ? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_clientId")//my id
            : _clientId;

        _secretId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_secretId)
            ? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_secretId") // my id
            : _secretId;


        AuthorizationCodeAuth auth =
            new AuthorizationCodeAuth(_clientId, _secretId, "http://localhost:5002", "http://localhost:5002", Scope.PlaylistReadPrivate | Scope.PlaylistReadCollaborative);
        auth.AuthReceived += AuthOnAuthReceived;
        auth.Start();
        auth.OpenBrowser();


        Console.ReadLine();
        auth.Stop(0);

    }

    private static async void AuthOnAuthReceived(object sender, 
    AuthorizationCode payload)
    {
        AuthorizationCodeAuth auth = (AuthorizationCodeAuth)sender;
        auth.Stop();

        Token token = await auth.ExchangeCode(payload.Code);
        SpotifyWebAPI api = new SpotifyWebAPI
        {
            AccessToken = token.AccessToken,
            TokenType = token.TokenType
        };
        PrintUsefulData(api);
    }

    private static async void PrintUsefulData(SpotifyWebAPI api)
    {

        RestClient rClient = new RestClient();
        rClient.endPoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums";
        string strResponse = string.Empty;
        strResponse = rClient.getRequest();

    }

}
```

}

```
public enum HttpVerb
{
    GET,
    POST,
    PUT,
    DELETE
}

class RestClient
{
    public string endPoint { get; set; }
    public HttpVerb httpMethod { get; set; }

    public RestClient()
    {
        endPoint = string.Empty;
        httpMethod = HttpVerb.GET;
    }

    public string getRequest()
    {
        string strResponseVal = string.Empty;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
        request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("error code: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        strResponseVal = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return strResponseVal;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So, you go all the way and set up a `SpotifyWebAPI` object with a (valid, i presume) access token and all that, then provide this `SpotifyWebAPI` object to the _PrintUsefulData_ method, and then.... um, i forgot what i was talking about... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple of things going on here but here's my shot at helping based on what code you've posted:

- **Token Expiration** - If you get a 401 error on a request then you need to use the `Refresh Token` which should have been supplied at the point of authorisation to get a new `Access Token`. This should apply to ANY call you make to the API.
- **Request Parameters** - The endpoint you're calling (`https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums`) requires the parameter `ids` so the Spotify API knows *what 'albums'* you would like to return. 
  More info: `https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/albums/get-several-albums/`

Another thing to check: 
- **Scope** - make sure when you Auth to the API you are setting the required scope you need to perform actions in the future. I don't think this applies specifically in this case but worth noting.